# Firebase function time-out when streaming file from Firebase Storage on emulator

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am new to node.js and back-end in general and trying to provide an API for downloading files for my pet project. For that I decided to host files in Firebase storage and provide access to them via Firebase Functions. To achieve that I am using following code:

```js
const app = express()

app.get('/:filename', async (request, response) => {
  const file = await admin.storage().bucket().getFiles({
    autoPaginate: false,
    delimiter: '/',
    prefix: 'files/'
  })
  .then(response => {
    const files = response[0]
    files.shift()
    return files[0] //let's take first file for example
  })

  response.attachment(`${filename}.zip`);
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', `${file.metadata.type}`) // application/zip
  response.setHeader('Content-Length', file.metadata.size)

  file.createReadStream()
  .pipe(response)
})

exports.styles = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

In terms of ability to download the file, when visiting the URL from browser, and opening it after download, all works, so no questions here.

What bugs me is that function doesn't end after serving the file and downloading is completed. Instead it throws a timeout error on emulator (haven't deployed this yet, so cannot say for sure if it is reproducible on live).

```
⚠  functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
>  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:642
>                  throw new Error("Function timed out.");
>                  ^
>  
>  Error: Function timed out.
>      at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:642:23)
>      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:551:17)
>      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:7)
```

I have also tried the following snippet, but result was same:

```js
file.createReadStream()
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log("end reading file stream. closing connection")
    response.end(() => console.log("connection closed"))
  })
  .pipe(response)
```

additionally, neither first nor second log statements are printed.
what's funny, this issue is not reproduced when script is deployed, this only occurs on the emulator.

I've done a little research on this, and found out that there are events fired during the stream, which could be handled and do `response.end()`, but apparently there is no need to do that when piping.

I am stuck now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a best practice, you have to handle the errors in your Cloud Functions using .catch() after .then()  to better manage and resolve the [errors](https://medium.com/@lucymarmitchell/using-then-catch-finally-to-handle-errors-in-javascript-promises-6de92bce3afc). Also please put end your Cloud Function correctly as stated in the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the timeout in your functions with:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300
}

exports.styles = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(app)
```

The maximum value for timeoutSeconds is 540, or 9 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase Official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request) states that we have to make sure that the functions are terminated properly:

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

So check when the createReadStream "ends" and then call the end() function of response.

```
file.createReadStream()
  .on('end', function() {
    response.end();
  })
  .pipe(response);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have actually tried this and this didnt work. i was still getting the timeout error. i'll update the OP to include this detail. btw, i have mentioned in the OP that during my research i stumbled upon a post saying that when piping to the `response`, there is no need to manually close. is it for a concrete node version or in general?

Comment: Something else to try is `return response.end();` You can actually return the whole thing. `return file.createReadStream().on(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the firebase function timeout in local emulator by setting the variable `FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=540s` in a file called `.env.local` in your functions directory.
Or start your emulator with `FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR_TIMEOUT_SECONDS=540 firebase emulators:start --only functions`.

Please refer the [comment here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2837#issuecomment-1048878134) in the firebase gitlab open issues